# Tighter fitting \boxed equation?

Tags: boxes

I use \boxed a lot to help me isolate elements in my notes. I would like to define a \snugboxed command so that it produces a tighter-fitting box than \boxed around the element inside my $..$ environment. Is that possible ?

for example in such code as this, ideally the box would fit the element inside tighter:

```
 $ f_{n+1}(\theta) = E  \theta^{Z_{n+1} } = 
 E \left(  \boxed{E\theta^{Z_{n+1}}|Z_n} \right) = 
  \sum \boxed{E  \left( \theta^{Z_{n+1}} | Z_n    \right)} 
  P(Z_n=k) \leftarrow \boxed{E  \theta^{Z_{n+1}} | Z_n}     $ 
is the random variable here !
```

thank you !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\boxed` is just a thin wrapper around `\fbox` and so uses the same `\fboxsep` padding, so if you (locally, or for the whole document) use

```
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
```

You will get a tighter fitting frame.