# Proof tree as argument to function, with tight-fitting box

Tags: vertical-alignment, bounding-box

I would like to define a function over proof trees, using [`mathpartir`](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/latex/) to layout the proofs. For example:
[image]
However, I would like the function parentheses to fit snugly around the inference rule.

I'm using `\mbox`, but that doesn't seem to work; I experimented with `\fbox` to see if [`\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}` had any effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358269), but it didn't (and I don't want a visible border anyway).

I can get better results with `\makebox`:

[image]

but that involves having to set the size manually for each case of the function.

A second constraint (illustrated by neither of my images) is that the proof tree argument should be **vertically centered** inside the parentheses.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpartir}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   f\left(
      \mbox{
         \begin{mathpar}
            \inferrule*
            {
               T \\
               U
            }
            {
               \rho, (e_1, e_2) \Rightarrow v
            }
         \end{mathpar}
      }
   \right)
   &=
   (f(T), f(U))
   \\
   f\left(
      \makebox[0.9in]{
         \begin{mathpar}
            \inferrule*
            {
               T \\
               U
            }
            {
               \rho, (e_1, e_2) \Rightarrow v
            }
         \end{mathpar}
      }
   \right)
   &=
   (f(T), f(U))
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @yo' Just added, sorry - forgot to include it!

Answer (score 1):

## **Solution 1.**

Why don't you just simply use `\frac` in the parentheses? It seems to have the layout which you want to achieve.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    f\left(\frac{T\qquad U}{\rho,(e_1,e_2)\Rightarrow v}\right) = (f(T),f(U))
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Solution 2.

If you are willing to manually play with lengths, you can try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathpartir}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
   f\left(\raisebox{-0.25cm}{\makebox[0.9in]{
    \begin{mathpar}
    \inferrule*
    {
        T \\
        U
    }
    {
        \rho, (e_1, e_2) \Rightarrow v
    }
    \end{mathpar}}}
\right)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ideally I would like to copy and paste from inference rules written using `mathpartir`. But this may be a useful alternative if I can't make progress  otherwise - thanks.